# Custom bool-to-str conversion in f-strings?

Tags: python, boolean, operator-overloading

I'm not satisfied with the standard boolean representation, which is "True" or "False". I'd like to see "SUCCESS" and "FAIL" everywhere in my logs. Can I overload the string conversion for boolean variables for my module somehow?

```
id = 4608
result = False
log(f"Operation {id} status : {result}")
```

> Operation 4608 status : FAIL

Answer (score 4):

Without really overriding the string conversion, you can use the following code to achieve your results

```
log(f"Operation {id} status : {'SUCCESS' if result else 'FAIL'}")
```

This would print `SUCCESS` if result is True and `FAIL` if its False

---

## Update :

Based on suggestion in comments by @matszwecja, you can always convert it into a function and than just call it, to avoid repetition

```
def bool_to_string(value: bool) -> str:
    if value:
        return "SUCCESS"
    return "FAIL"

log(f"Operation {id} status : {bool_to_string(result)}")
```

Comment: I'd encapsulate this in a function to avoid some repetition, but otherwise that's the way that will cause least amount of problems imho.

Comment: Yeah, that's an approach. But it makes strings longer and code more verbose. Even if I name my function b(...), it will increase a number of braces to four. I hoped, there is some magic to avoid that :)